# Angular Cards to be the same height in a flex-layout row

Tags: html, css, angular, flexbox, angular-material2

I have an angular material based ui. I am using `@material/flex-layout` and material cards, so I have a component layout like:

```
<div class="container" fxLayout fxLayout.xs="column" fxLayoutAlign="center" fxLayoutGap="10px" fxLayoutGap.xs="0">
    <div fxFlex="30%">
        <md-card>
            <h3>Last 30 Days</h3>
            <app-oee30 [target]="target" [cell]="cell"></app-oee30>
        </md-card>
    </div>
    <div fxFlex="70%">
        <md-card>
            <h3>24 hours of OEE (target: {{target}}%):</h3>
            <app-oee24 [target]="target" [cell]="cell"></app-oee24>
        </md-card>
    </div>
</div>
```

which looks like this:

[image]

Obviously, the fact that the two boxes aren't the same height looks weird. How can I easily (and responsively), ensure they are the same height?
Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can add `fxLayoutAlign=" stretch"` to the 70% div. [Plunker demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/VH8ILGq7574m3SVsT84w?p=preview)

```
<div fxFlex="70%" `fxLayoutAlign=" stretch"`>
```

That should do the trick.

Just an fyi, you can use this [demo](https://tburleson-layouts-demos.firebaseapp.com/#/docs) to try different flex-layout alignment.

Comment: this does not work. It stretch vertically but the widths are broken then